# Pass variables into Facebook iFrame app PHP

Tags: php, facebook, variables, iframe, tabs

I thought this was possible, but it doesn't seem like I can do it.

What I'm looking at doing is passing a variable ***into*** a facebook iframe application. It doesn't matter how, but I've been trying a couple different methods. If anyone has any idea.

-----edit---------

Yes (to below), I found the items if anyone else looks for this use…

Create links...

```
$link_params = array(
    'item1' => "blah",
    'item2'   => "blaaaaargh"
);
$encodedParams = urlencode(json_encode( $link_params )); 
//added to link as app_data
```

Get data…

```
if (!empty($signed_request) && !empty($signed_request['app_data'])) {
  $app_data = json_decode($signed_request['app_data'], true);
} //use in your app from here as $app_data['item1']
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do.?

Comment: I wanted the app to be able to post something on a wall, and then post a link to it. However for the person to comment/like that I needed to get them to like the page then redirect. So I needed the app to be able to accept and remember the link (session variables) to pass it on..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is acutally something: the `app_data` in the [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). The documentation says:

> A JSON string containing the content of a query string parameter also
>   called app_data. Usually specified when the application built the link
>   to pass some data to itself. Only available if your app is an iframe
>   loaded in a Page tab.

This means, you simply call your app, add `&app_data=...` to the url. Remember to encode the parameters to json first.

Comment: Yes, I found the items if anyone else looks for this use… 

Get data…
if (!empty($signed_request) && !empty($signed_request['app_data'])) {
  $app_data = json_decode($signed_request['app_data'], true);
}

Create links...
$link_params = array(
 'item1' => "blah",
 'item2'   => "blaaaaargh"
);
$encodedParams = urlencode(json_encode( $link_params )); //added to link as app_data