# $_GET on facebook iframe app

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm trying to pass some data using GET method on my iframe facecbook app , but inside the page there is no data , my code is

```
<?php 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
die()
?>
```

and trying to pass like apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/?p=23
or apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/index.php?p=23

Comment: Is that the entire page code? It sounds like there may be some redirect going on that is losing the query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can' directly pass a variable into the iframe, you need the **app_data** in the signed request. Look at these similar questions and answers:

- [Bookmark facebook app with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744610/bookmark-facebook-app-with-parameter/6747492#6747492)
- [Pass variables into Facebook iFrame app PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714987/pass-variables-into-facebook-iframe-app-php/6721406#6721406)

Comment: This is the way you want to go. Use the `app_data` parameter and define a object so you can parse more into the app. This is the only parameter which Facebook recognize. Your URL would look like this then: http://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/?app_data={"this":"is","transfered":"toFacebook"}

Answer (score 1):

Forget what the other poster said. Normal canvas apps do not accept the app_data parameter, only tab apps do. But you can use custom URLs beyond just the canvas URL. Let me show you how this works.

**My App:**

I have an app called PulseTrack. The main App URL is:

http://apps.facebook.com/pulsetrack/

Which points to this canvas URL:

http://mydomain.com/pulsetrack/

But I can also use this url:

http://apps.facebook.com/pulsetrack/watch/EP011583610051

Which points to:

http://mydomain.com/pulsetrack/watch/EP011583610051

**Your app**

Using straight up PHP if you can setup your canvas URL like this:

http://yourdomain.com/index.php?

Then you can pass directory parameters to the end of your URL like so:

http://apps.facebook.com/your-app/your/awesome/params

Which will come to you like this:

http://yourdomain.com/index.php?/your/awesome/params

Something like this should be able to parse those "parameters" from the query string

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$params = explode("/", $query);
```

Best of luck, this took me a long to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

You can just pass the paramater in as per normal. Facebook will append it to the URL when it loads the iframe so what you are doing should in theory be working. Facebook actually does a HTTP POST when loading in the iframe however the resource will contain the query string you specify so in PHP $_GET should be filled in. How exactly are you passing the paramater? Give us an example of your code with link included.

Comment: I was trying to access the page like http://apps.facebook.com/appname/index.php?page=2 and when i print_r($_GET) its blank .

Comment: I tried the same and it doesn't work. I can add in the settings for my app where i list the url "?myparam=1234" but what I want is to write it in the URL.